# Import loop only works twice, gives pygame.error Display surface quit

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am in a beginner python class and we are working on our final projects. For my game however I wanted to be able to restart the game within itself. I did this by using imports to launch a new script to then re-run my game. However whenever I try to do it more than once my window breaks, or the code does not import the next file. My game is kinda long so I've created a very short program to give an example of my issue.

(This being the file yin.py)

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0) 
pygame.init()
SIZE = [300, 300]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            import yang
            done = True
    
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

(and this file yang.py)

```
import pygame

WHITE = (255, 255, 255) 
pygame.init()
SIZE = [300, 300]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            import yin 
            done = True
    
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

I've tried doing multiple things but so far I have gotten nowhere, it still is giving me display not initialized even though I have 'pygame.init()'. My teacher isn't responding to my emails and I have an encroaching deadline. Any help will be appreciated. :p

Answer (score 1):

The "import" statement only imports once.  If the name already exists, it doesn't import again.  You should put your code into a function.  Then, you can call the function as many times as you want.

Comment: And as an addendum, circular imports (that is, two files importing each other) are rarely a good sign.